# Timestamp in a cell when another cell is modified based on a dropbox

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I am trying to create a table where when I change the status for a task in Done in a cell then in a different I will have the timestamp of the "Done" status.

[image]

So, in attached picture in column D I have a `Dropbox` with "Done", "Ongoing" and "On hold". In column E I used this formula to put the timestamp for Done status:

`=IF(D4="DONE",IF(E4="DONE",E4,NOW()),"")`.

Timestamp is working, so that is fine, but when I change another task that was ongoing into "Done", then the timestamp modifies for the whole column. and I don't want that. I want for each cell to have an independent time stamp like I have in column B. In column B, I used the same formula correlating with cell C, when data is entered in cell B, then timestamp will appear in cell C.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the formula is recalculated at any time that Excel thinks it should be recalculated, and therefore the timestamp is updated.

You could use some VBA code instead. Put a [Change-Eventhandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) into the code of the sheet and set the timestamp if a cell in column D is changed to "Done". Your code could look like that:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if cell in column D was changed, if not, we're done.
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False    ' Disable events to prevent recursive call of change
    On Error GoTo change_exit           ' Ensure that events are enabled even if error occurs
    
    ' Check if more than one cell was changed (eg by using cut and paste)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please change only one cell at a time"
        Application.Undo
        GoTo change_exit
    End If
    
    ' Now check if value was changed to "Done" and set timestamp
    If LCase(Target.Value) = "done" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
    End If
change_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```